# Element disappear after sending HTTP request from client?

Tags: jquery, html, httprequest

I make a simple webpage with a couple of elements. I am using web services APIs and send HTTP request to perform actions.

**Problem:**
When I click on `Transfer` button the `div` element is disappear. Want to figure-out the reason why it show such kind of behavior?

I want this `div` element stable on the webpage after sending HTTP request so that I perform some other function.

Here is code:

**MyPage.html**

```
<div id="actions-call-control">
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <tr class="info">
                <td>
                 <input type="button" class="btn btn-mini btn-primary"  value="Transfer" id="button-message-control-transfer" onclick="transferMessage();" />
               </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
</div>
```

**Sample.js**

```
function transferMessage() {
   var callId = $("#field-call-control-callid").val();
   _finesse.transferMessage(callId, _extension, _handler, _handler); //http request
}
function _handler(data) {
    print2Console("RESPONSE", data);
}
function print2Console(type, data) {
    var date = new Date(),
    xml = null;
    consoleArea = $("#console-area");

    if (type === "EVENT") {
        $fromAddress = $(xml).find("fromAddress");

        if ($fromAddress.text() != '') // checking if the notification is a CALL
        {
            $("#actions-message-control").show();
            ANI = $fromAddress.text();
            ...
        }
        else {
            $("#actions-message-control").hide(); // hide call controls after call dropped/ended
        }
```

**finesse.js**

```
this.transferMessage = function (callId, myExtension, handler, errHandler) {
         var method = "PUT",
         url = _webappPath + "/api/Dialog/" + callId,
         xml = "<Dialog><requestedAction>TRANSFER</requestedAction><targetMediaAddress>" + myExtension + "</targetMediaAddress></Dialog>";
         _sendReq(url, method, null, null, handler, errHandler, false, xml);
     };
```

Need Help?

Comment: What is  _finesse.transferMessage(callId, _extension, _handler, _handler); , is this even defined/declared/initialized anywhere?

Comment: There is most probably some instruction for removing it. My first guess would be somewhere in the `_finesse.transferMessage` method...
As a side remark, it is bad practice to use inline javascript (= `onclick` attribute)

Comment: let me edit my question.

Comment: Also look in `_handler` for code that might remove DOM nodes.

Comment: Please post the code for the callbacks handler and errHandler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is actually with the handler.  When we click on `Transfer` button than bunch of event call and the last event (xml response) has empty `$fromAddress.text()`, that's why div is hide. So there is no problem with html.The solution is that there should be condition on `state` because `fromAddress` is empty and it's `<state>` is `WORK_READY` at last event response. The code work for me is :

```
if ($fromAddress.text() != ''){
    $("#actions-message-control").show();
            ANI = $fromAddress.text();
            ...
}
else {
            $state = $(xml).find("state");
            if ($state.text() === "WORK_READY") {
                $("#actions-call-control").show();
            }
            else {
                $("#actions-call-control").hide();
            }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Although, it's not a solution to 'why is it being removed?' but there is a way to make sure the element remains visible, all the time. Just change the function `transferMessage()` as follows:

```
function transferMessage() {
   var callId = $("#field-call-control-callid").val();
   _finesse.transferMessage(callId, _extension, _handler, _handler); //http request
   $('#actions-call-control').show(); // to make sure that the element remains visible
}
```